# How can one calculate percentage from previous week in aggregate query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a challenge I set out to do that seemed initially trivial. Not so for my developper brain.

Consider the following simple view, used to validate a cron that queries a subset of 200 000 statements every saturday.

It goes as follows:

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     DATE_FORMAT(s.created, "%Y-%m-%d") as "Date",
    ->     count(s.id) AS "Accounts credited",
    ->     sum(s.withdrawal) "Total Credited"
    ->   --  100 * (sum(s.withdrawal) - sum(prev.withdrawal)) 
         --   / sum(prev.withdrawal) "Difference in %"
    ->     FROM statements s
    -> --    LEFT JOIN prev
    -> --        s.created - interval 7 DAY
    ->  --     ON prev.created = s.created - interval 7 DAY 
        --     AND (prev.status_id = 'OPEN' 
        --     OR prev.status_id = 'PENDING')
    ->     WHERE (s.status_id = 'OPEN' OR  s.status_id = 'PENDING')
    ->     GROUP BY YEAR(s.created), MONTH(s.created), DAY(s.created)
    ->       ORDER BY s.created DESC
    ->     LIMIT 8;

+------------+-------------------+----------------+
| Date       | Accounts credited | Total Credited |
+------------+-------------------+----------------+
| 2019-01-19 |             18175 |        3173.68 |
| 2019-01-12 |             18135 |        4768.43 |
| 2019-01-05 |             17588 |        6968.49 |
| 2018-12-29 |             17893 |        5404.18 |
| 2018-12-22 |             17353 |        7048.18 |
| 2018-12-15 |             16893 |        7181.34 |
| 2018-12-08 |             16220 |        9547.09 |
| 2018-12-01 |             15476 |        7699.59 |
+------------+-------------------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.79 sec)
```

As is, the query is efficient and practical.  I merely would like to add a column,  `difference in percentage`, from previous week's total, as seen with the -- commented out code.

I have tried various approaches, but because of the `GROUP BY`, adding an inline column to get the `sum(withdrawal)` of previous week makes the query run ... forever.

I then tried the `LEFT JOIN` approach, but this has the same problem, Obviously.  I think the added `JOIN` has to fetch the sum of previous week for every row of the outer select.

I then had the (not so smart) idea of querying my view, even but then it seems I would have the same issue.

I assume there are much more optimal approaches out there to this simple task.

Is there an elegant way to calculate a percentage from such a query?

Would a stored procedure or some other 'non-plain-sql' approach be more optimal?

Comment: What version of mysql are you on.

Comment: You appear to have done all the hard work and got down to 8 rows, why not make this a sub query and in the main query work out the % change

Comment: @P.Salmon 5.5.57, I have 5.7 staged going into production in a a few weeks, so 5.7  is approach is also fine.

Comment: As suggested  by P.Salmon .. join a subquery  based on the result for previous week should be a solution

Comment: I wouldn't completely agree with it being "efficient". When you apply functions like `DATE_FORMAT`, 'YEAR', `MONTH' and 'DAY` to a query, it will churn pretty hard on each row of the data. Plus, I don't think it will use an index on your `created` column. And if that query returned 8 rows in .79 seconds, that's not going to scale very well.

Comment: You might be able to go back to the original to get at this data a little easier. I'm guessing `prev` is a view?

Comment: @Shawn - Did I mention I was a dev-ops/ app developper, with no DBA to assist ? <sheepish grin> I am curious though, and would be grateful if you point out the optimal DATE_FORMAT equivalent?

Comment: @P.Salmon - you mean,  left join with the view?

Comment: @stefgosselin Afer reading back over my message, I came across a bit more rude than I intended to be. So I apologize for my snippiness. As far as more optimal date processing, I've always found working with dates can be a pain. I usually go with my standard solution of using a Date Dimension to join to. It should significantly speed up processing and should still allow you to use an index. Especially if you're working on 100k+ records. But with all things, testing is always the only way to really know what works best.

Answer (score 1):

I used this query in SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 8
    DATE_FORMAT(s.created, "%Y-%m-%d") as "Date",
    count(s.id) AS "Accounts credited",
    sum(s.withdrawal) "Total Credited",
    100 * (sum(s.withdrawal) - sum(s1.withdrawal)) / sum(s1.withdrawal) "Difference in %"
FROM statements s
    LEFT JOIN statements s1 ON s1.created = s.created - 7
    AND (s1.status_id = 'OPEN' OR s1.status_id = 'PENDING')
WHERE (s.status_id = 'OPEN' OR  s.status_id = 'PENDING')
GROUP BY YEAR(s.created), MONTH(s.created), DAY(s.created)
ORDER BY s.created DESC
```

> Your just handle null or zero s1.withdrawal.

I wish it work.

Comment: Why would a query that doesn't run in MySQL get an upvote?

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with your original query then a correlated sub query like so may be all you need

```
select t.*,
         (select totalcredited from t t1 where t1.dt < t.dt order by t1.dt desc limit 1) prev,
         (
         totalcredited / (select totalcredited from t t1 where t1.dt < t.dt order by t1.dt desc limit 1)  * 100
         ) -100 as chg
from  (your query) as t;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed a mistake in my previous example so here's an update.
NOTE: the query compares the current week with the previous one.
I hope that this is what you need.

```
SELECT
    Date,
    SUM(CASE week WHEN 0 THEN accounts_credited ELSE 0 END) AS 'Accounts credited',
    SUM(CASE week WHEN 0 THEN total_credited ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total Credited',
    100 * (
        SUM(CASE week WHEN 0 THEN total_credited ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE week WHEN 1 THEN total_credited ELSE 0 END)
    ) / SUM(CASE week WHEN 1 THEN total_credited ELSE 0 END) AS 'Difference in %'
FROM
(SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(created, '%Y-%m-%d') as 'Date',
    COUNT(id) AS 'accounts_credited',
    SUM(withdrawal) 'total_credited',
    0 AS 'week'
FROM 
    statements
WHERE 
    status_id IN ('OPEN','PENDING')
AND
    YEARWEEK(created, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)
GROUP BY 
    DATE(created)
UNION
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(created, '%Y-%m-%d') as 'Date',
    COUNT(id) AS 'accounts_credited',
    SUM(withdrawal) 'total_credited',
    1 AS 'week'
FROM 
    statements
WHERE 
    status_id IN ('OPEN','PENDING')
AND
    (
    DATE(created) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())+6 DAY
    AND 
    DATE(created) < CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())-1 DAY
    )
GROUP BY 
    DATE(created)
) AS tmp
ORDER BY Date
GROUP BY Date
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
select date_format(s.created, '%Y-%m-%d') as "Date",
       count(*) AS "Accounts credited",
       sum(s.withdrawal) "Total Credited"
from statements s
where s.status_id in ('OPEN', 'PENDING')
group by date_format(s.created, '%Y-%m-%d')
order by s.created desc
limit 8;
```

In MySQL, perhaps the simplest solution is variables.  However, because of the rules around MySQL variables, this is a bit complicated:

```
select s.*,
       (case when (@new_prev := @prev) = NULL then NULL  -- never gets here
             when (@prev := Total_Credited) = NULL then NULL -- never gets here
             else @new_prev
        end) as previous_week_Total_Credited
from (select date_format(s.created, '%Y-%m-%d') as "Date",
             count(*) AS Accounts_credited,
             sum(s.withdrawal) as Total_Credited
      from statements s
      where s.status_id in ('OPEN', 'PENDING')
      group by date_format(s.created, '%Y-%m-%d')
      order by "Date" desc
     ) s cross join
     (select @prev := NULL) params
 limit 8;
```

You can then just use this as a subquery for your final calculation.